# ElasticSearch API with React App giving Unauthorized (401) on a search rqeuest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, elasticsearch, search

I have a simple react app from which I am trying to connect to elasticsearch as follows:

```
import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";

let client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9200',
    log: 'trace',
    auth: {
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password'
           }
    });
```

After this, I am trying to send a request to ElasticSearch as follows:

```
client.search(JSON.parse('{"index":"my-index","body":{"size":"6" etc etc}').then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
});
```

But as a response, I always get back **Unauthorized (401)**

[image]

Everything works fine in Kibana, browser or Postman. I have also tried authenticating with an API_KEY from Kibana but I get the same response back. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After alot of trial and error, I found out that this works (for anybody have the same problem):

```
 var auth = 'username:password';
        var port = 9200;
        var protocol = 'https';
        var hostUrls = [
            'xxx.xxx.xx.xx',
        ];

        var hosts = hostUrls.map(function(host) {
            return {
                protocol: protocol,
                host: host,
                port: port,
                auth: auth
            };
        });

        var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
            hosts: hosts,
            log: "trace",
        });
```

I don't know why this works and to be honest I dont even care, I'm just happy it works. Javascript voodoo magic